# Incorrect amounts on order when custom currency set on quote

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, quote

So when I create an order programmatically, I use the following lines to set a custom currency different from the base, in this example GBP as custom and EUR as base. I also select the store to use:

```
Mage::app()->getStore($store)->setCurrentCurrency(Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->load("GBP"));
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId("1");
$quote->setBaseCurrencyCode((Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->load("EUR"));
$quote->setQuoteCurrencyCode(Mage::getModel('directory/currency')->load("GBP"));
```

As can now be seen, the correct currency is now applied and calculations are correct for subtotals and tax. Including the custom currency and base currency.

[image: Correct]

My problem occurs when I am trying this on our live server, it appears to set the custom currency values the same as the base currency. This is causing us many issues in accounting.

[image: Incorrect]

Any help on resolving this problem would be greatly appreciated.